# Container is not accessible via kubernetes readiness probe

Tags: kubernetes

I see this error in `kubectl describe podName`:

```
  9m        2s      118 kubelet, gke-wordpress-default-pool-2e82c1f4-0zpw   spec.containers{nginx}      Warning     Unhealthy       Readiness probe failed: Get http://10.24.0.27:80/: net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

The container logs (nginx) is of the following:

```
10.24.1.1 - - [22/Aug/2017:11:09:51 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"
```

However if I exec into the container via `kubectl exec -it podName -c nginx sh`, and do a wget `http://localhost` I am able to succesfully get a HTTP 200 response. As well as if I SSH into the host (GCP compute instance), I'm able to successfully get a HTTP 200 response.

I believe this issue occurred shortly after I replace a LoadBalancer service with a NodePort service. I wonder if it's some port conflict?

The service in question:
**wordpress-service.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: wordpress
  name: wordpress
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: wordpress
```

The container is a Nginx container serving content on port 80.

What might be the cause of the readiness probe failing?

---

If I remove the readiness probe in my config:

```
      readinessProbe:
        httpGet:
          path: /
          port: 80
        initialDelaySeconds: 5 
        periodSeconds: 5
```

Everything works fine, the pods are able to be accessed via a LoadBalancer service.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ARGHUGIHIRHHHHHH.

I've been staring at this error for a day at least and for some reason I didn't comprehend it.

Essentially the error `net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)` means the container took longer then the timeout period (default of 1s).

Comment: so does the probe's timeout seconds needs to be increased...i am facing the same issue as well..my container is accessible externally through an ALB or directly from browser but readiness probe always fails with client.timeout error.